# Check if all elements of list are prime in Raku

Tags: mapreduce, raku

```
my @g = (1,2,3,4);
say reduce {is-prime}, @g; # ==> gives error
say reduce {is-prime *}, @g; #==> gives error
say reduce {is-prime}, (1,2,3,4); # ==> gives error
say so is-prime @g.all; # ==> gives error
```

How to check if all elements of list are prime in Raku?

Comment: I'm not getting an error with `so is-prime @g.all`, although it makes most sense to me to write it as `so is-prime all @g` or `?@g.all.is-prime`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're basically asking: are there any elements in this list which are **not** prime?  I would write that as:

```
say "not all prime" if @g.first: !*.is-prime;
```

Please note though, that apparently **1** is *not* considered prime according to the `is-prime` function:

```
say 1.is-prime;  # False
```

so the `first` would trigger on the **1** in your example, not on the **4**.

Comment: Good idea to iterate the list with the `first` with a lambda.

Comment: That should really be `with` not `if`. What if the first value was `0`?

Comment: Even using `with` in this case, wouldn't catch if the actual element is a type-object, such as with `(Int,Str,Date).first: { $_ ~~ Str }`.  So you need to look at the actual situation where this is used.  Since we don't check whether `0` is a prime, the `if` should do fine :-)

Comment: Which is why `grep` is better for this than `first`.

Comment: Not really, as `grep` will always test *all* of the elements, it doesn't short-circuit.  You *can* use `first` always, by using the `:k` adverb and `with`: `say "found" with (Int,Str,Date).first(Int, :k);  # found`

Answer (score 9):

The answers above are all helpful, but they fail to explain why your solution does not work. Basically [reduce](https://docs.raku.org/routine/reduce) is not going to apply a function (in your case, is-prime) to every member of a list. You want [map](https://docs.raku.org/routine/map) for that. The error says

```
Calling is-prime() will never work with signature of the proto ($, *%)
```

Because `reduce` expects an infix, thus binary, function, or a function with two arguments; what it does is to apply them to the first pair of elements, then to the result and the third element, and so on. Last statement does not work for a similar reason: you are calling is-prime with a list argument, not a single argument.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer as it explains why my trials didn't work. I formed my solution mimicking `say reduce { $^a + $^b }, (1,2,3);`  now we know why it didn't work, because `reduce` expects a function with two arguments but `is-prime` operates on one argument.

Answer (score 5):

There are of course may ways to do this. A very explicit way is using a for loop:

```
for @g -> $g {
 if $g.is-prime {
  say $g;
 }
}
```

Or with a grep (you could leave the $_ implicit):

```
@g.grep({ $_.is-prime }).say
```

Both above are assuming you really want to filter the primes out. Of course you can also really *check* each number and get a boolean:

```
@g.map({ .is-prime }).say
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I was trying to get just one endresult, i.e. either `True` of `False` The samples are still helpful as they show how to properly iterate the list.

Comment: FYI. An idiomatic way to express that without parens/braces is `say @g .grep: *.is-prime`. The `*` is the same as it is in the `+*` I mentioned in a `where` clause in my answer to your first SO. In this case you get (the same as) `{ $_.is-prime }`. The `.grep: ...` is an alternative to `.grep(...)`. You can't use `.foo: ...` if you want/need to chain method calls but it's often nice if you don't.

Answer (score 5):

There is a big problem with this:

```raku
say reduce {is-prime}, @g;
```

You created a lambda:

```raku
{  }
```

The only thing it does is calls a function:

```raku
is-prime
```

You didn't give the function any arguments though.
Is it just supposed to guess what the arguments should be?

If you meant to pass in `is-prime` as a reference, you should have used `&is-prime` rather than `{is-prime}`.
Of course that still wouldn't have worked.

The other problem is that `reduce` operates by recursively combining values.
It can't do that if it operates on one argument at a time.
The bare block lambda `{}`, takes zero or one argument, not two or more.

---

`reduce` is often combined with `map`.

It happens so often that there is a Wikipedia page about [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

```raku
say ( map &is-prime, @g ==> reduce { $^a and $^b } );
# False

say ( map &is-prime, 2,3,5 ==> reduce { $^a and $^b } );
# True
```

I wrote it that way so that `map` would be in the line before `reduce`, but perhaps it would be more clear this way:

```raku
say reduce {$^a and $^b}, map &is-prime, 2,3,5;
# True
```

`reduce` with an infix operator is so common that there is a shorter way to write it.

```raku
say [and] map &is-prime, 2,3,5;
# True
```

---

Of course it would be better to just find the first value that isn't prime, and say the inverse.

Since if there is even a single value that isn't prime that would mean they can't all be primes.

You have to be careful though, as you may think something like this would always work:

```raku
not @g.first: !*.is-prime;
```

It does happen to work for the values you gave it, but may not always.
`first` returns `Nil` if it can't find the value.

```raku
not (2,3,5).first: !*.is-prime;
# not Nil === True

not (2,3,4).first: !*.is-prime;
# not 4   === False

not (2,3,0,4).first: !*.is-prime;
# not 0   === True
```

That last one returned `0` which when combined with `not` returns `True`.

You could fix this with `defined`.

```raku
not defined (2,3,0,4).first: !*.is-prime;
# False
```

This only works if `first` wouldn't return an undefined element that happens to be in the list.

```raku
(Int,Any).first: Real
# Int

defined (Int,Any).first: Real
# False
```

You could fix that by asking for the index instead of the value.
You of course still need `defined`.

```raku
(Int,Any).first: :k, Real
# 0

defined (Int,Any).first: :k, Real
# True
```

The other way to fix it is to just use `grep`.

```raku
not (2,3,0,4).grep: !*.is-prime;
# not (0,4) === False
```

Since `grep` always returns a `List`, you don't have to worry about checking for `0` or undefined elements.
(A `List` is `True` if it contains any elements, no matter what the values.)

`grep` is smart enough to know that if you coerce to `Bool` that it can stop upon finding the first value.
So it short-circuits the same as if you had used `first`.

---

This results in some fairly funky code, with those two negating operators. So it should be put into a function.

```raku
sub all-prime ( +@_ ) {
  # return False if we find any non-prime
  not @_.grep: !*.is-prime
  # grep short-circuits in Bool context, so this will stop early
}
```

This could still fail if you give it something weird

```raku
all-prime 2,3,5, Date.today;
# ERROR: No such method 'is-prime' for invocant of type 'Date'
```

If you care, add some error handling.

```raku
sub all-prime ( +@_ ) {
  # return Nil if there was an error
  CATCH { default { return Nil }}

  # return False if we find any non-prime
  not @_.grep: !*.is-prime
}

all-prime 2,3,5, Date.today;
# Nil
```

Answer (score 3):

use the `all` junction:

```
say so all @g».is-prime; # False
```

Comment: Using a hyperoperator is a good idea as it makes the code shorter and evaluating the resulting list with the `all` (is it called a junction or a method here?)  is a good idea too. It's really helpful.

Comment: This works indeed.  But this will create a `Junction` with *all* of its eigenstates, before the `so` can short-circuit on the first `False` eigenstate encountered.  Since `.is-prime` can get very expensive, the fact that *all* of these calculations need to be done first, will probably make this approach have a comparable  speed to the `.first` solution *only* if the very last eigenstate is `False`.  In all other cases, the `first` approach will probably be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: ElizabethMittijsen: Wouldn't that be changed if this were instead `@g.all.is-prime`, thus shifting the costly ops to the short-circuitable junction?  (I'm actually surprised no one has suggestioned `@g.all.is-prime`, since it's the most readable for me personally)

Comment: @user0721090601 I think (hope) you're right. Of course, that will still leave the junction slower because junctions are slower, even if the short circuiting is (hopefully) algorithmically the same given your formulation. On a somewhat related note, but with a view to a hoped for future in which short circuiting evaluation can nix unneeded parallel computations that actually occur in parallel, I'd truly love it if you could read [this comment by me](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2676#issuecomment-461457703) and lmk if you understand what I was driving at or ask for clarification. TIA.

Comment: The short-circuiting happens with the `so`, well, technically in the `Junction.Bool`.  For that, the whole `Junction` must be built.